# How can I print error messages from my function when the arguments are invalid?

Tags: java

I just started to learn Java. There is a course in MIT and there is [an assignment](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-092-introduction-to-programming-in-java-january-iap-2010/assignments/MIT6_092IAP10_assn02.pdf) to write a class for pay calculation. Part of the task is:

> - The base pay must not be less than the minimum wage ($8.00 an hour). If it is, print an error.
> - If the number of hours is greater than 60, print an error message.

The code I have written is as follows:

```
public class fooCorporation {
    private float totalPay;
    private float calc;

    public float totalPay(double basePay, int hours){

        if(hours <= 40){
            totalPay = (float) (basePay * hours);
        }
        else if(hours > 40){
            int extraHours =  hours - 40;
            float payForFortyHours = (float) (basePay * hours);
            float payForextraHours = (float) (basePay * 1.5 * extraHours);

            totalPay = payForFortyHours + payForextraHours;
        }
        return totalPay;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        fooCorporation foo = new fooCorporation();
        System.out.println("employee 1: " + foo.totalPay(7.50,35));
        System.out.println("employee 2: " + foo.totalPay(8.20,47));
        System.out.println("employee 3: " + foo.totalPay(10.00,73));
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is how to print an error message from the function `totalPay()` when some conditions are not met. Can the above logic be written in a different way?

Comment: So... you can see how to print things, from main().  You could do similar things in totalPay().  What are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally *don't* print things in the middle of general purpose functions since (1) it's annoying to the people using those functions; and (2) it gives no indication of a problem to the calling *code.*

Usually, you would either throw an exception or have some specific return code indicating an error condition.

Then the *caller* can decide what to print (or do otherwise if printing is not appropriate).

For example, if you can determine that the total pay should always be positive, just return `-1.0` for an error condition. For example:

```
public class fooCorporation {
    public float totalPay (double basePay, int hours) {
        if (hours < 0) return -1.0;
        if (hours <= 40) return (float) (basePay * hours);

        int extraHours =  hours - 40;
        float payForFortyHours = (float) (basePay * hours);
        float payForextraHours = (float) (basePay * 1.5 * extraHours);

        return payForFortyHours + payForextraHours;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        fooCorporation foo = new fooCorporation();
        float pay = foo.totalPay (7.50, 35);
        if (pay < 0) System.out.println ("employee 1: invalid hours");
        else         System.out.println ("employee 1: " + pay);

        pay = foo.totalPay (8.20, 47);
        if (pay < 0) System.out.println ("employee 2: invalid hours");
        else         System.out.println ("employee 2: " + pay);

        pay = foo.totalPay (10.00, -4);
        if (pay < 0) System.out.println ("employee 3: invalid hours");
        else         System.out.println ("employee 3: " + pay);
    }
}
```

---

That method of yours, by the way, gives you *double* time and a half (`x2.5`) for overtime since you're not adjusting the base hours down to 40. Make sure that's what you want rather than time and a half (`x1.5`).

Comment: I would emphasize exceptions more strongly.  Error codes should be reserved for when invalid input is expected and not a programming error. (i.e.  `String.indexOf`)

Comment: Some people prefer to leave exceptions for truly exceptional conditions such as terminal input errors or comms issues. They do not subscribe to the "invalid input parameter is an exception" way of thinking. You could go either way in my opinion. In any case, the return code is an _example,_ not a definitive solution.

Answer (score 2):

The `totalPay()` method looks good as written. What you could do now is add another method that handles all of the printing. Here's some code that shows the overall idea. I've left gaps in there for you to fill in.

```
public void printPay(int employeeNum, double basePay, int hours) {
    if (...) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    else if (...) {
        System.out.println("different error");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("employee X: " + totalPay(...));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    fooCorporation foo = new fooCorporation();

    printPay(1, 7.50,  35);
    printPay(2, 8.20,  47);
    printPay(3, 10.00, 73);
}
```

The nice thing about using the `totalPay()` function you already wrote is that it organizes the code in nice, small, manageable chunks. One function does calculations and the other handles printing. Each function has its unique role.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should handle a negative number of hours passed in; for example:

```
public float totalPay(double basePay, int hours) throws Exception{
{
if(hours<0)
   throw new Exception("Hours cannot be a negative number");
if(basePay<=0)
   throw new Exception("Base pay cannot be a negative number");
   ...//the rest of the implementation
}
```

HOWEVER, throwing `Exception` as above is generally [**bad practice.**](http://www.hans-eric.com/2009/10/31/the-bad-practices-of-exception-handling/). Defining your own Exception class and throwing specifically that Exception, *when necessary (for example when a standard Java Exception does not perfectly fit in the situation at hand)*, is a best practice because it gives more useful information as to what had gone wrong on the program and gives the developer a chance to react in an easier, cleaner and more granular way to the specific situation. For example, some Exceptions may be considered fatal while others may be catched and easy to recover from. In cases where it makes sense to define your own Exception as opposed to using one of the Java's standard library is the following:

```
class BadParameterException extends Exception {
   public BadParameterException(String msg){
      super(msg);
   }
}
```

And in your specific example you could flag your method as throws `BadParameterException` as so:

```
public float totalPay(double basePay, int hours) throws BadParameterException {
       if(hours<0)
        throw new BadParameterException ("Hours cannot be a negative number");
 ... // and so on
 }
```

Comment: you should NEVER throw `Exception`, this is terrible advice for someone learning Java. And `InvalidParameterException` should be `IllegalArgumentException` which is already a standard Exception available in the JDK and what is used by all the Standard library code.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson do you care to explain WHY is a terrible advice?

Comment: `throw Exception` leads to `catch(Exception e);` which is well documented as always wrong.

Comment: It's a good practice to write your own exceptions when you need them, but this seems like a duplicate of IllegalArgumentException. The only purpose would be that it's a checked exceptions, if you really want this.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I think I know what you meant but I also see that your problem is really reading comprehension more than anything else. Didn't I say that it is a good practice to DEFINE your OWN Exception and THROW THAT EXCEPTION? DIDN'T I provide an EXAMPLE of HOW TO DO THAT?

Comment: @captaincomic I don't know if IllegalArgumentException exists in Java or not. My point is to demonstrate how to define your own (call it FooException, if that's what you want) and throw it when it makes sense to do it.

Comment: @Icarus I read the entire answer and still felt strongly enough to make my comment. **The first thing you show is the wrong way to do it**, very few people will read past that, **just putting that example there is passively promoting a extremely terrible practice**, it should **never** be an option. Also not using what is already in the Standard library is not good advice either. Why suggest duplication of [IllegalArgumentException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), that is bad advice as well.

Comment: @Icarus Yes, and it's a good point that you can write your own exceptions. In many cases it's a good idea (e.g. if there is no exception in the standard library that fits your situation, or if you want to wrap lower level exceptions, etc.). Also in this example you can do it, but I would just use IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Effective Java, item #60 - 'Favor the use of standard exceptions'. Bloch goes into detail here on why you should normally NOT go out of your way to create your own Exception subclasses.

Comment: @wolfcastle I agree. I wasn't trying to imply that you should *always* define your own, but rather to stress the point that sometimes it makes sense to define your own and throw that. I've have edited my answer to avoid misinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: just saw the link going to try to read your assignemtn

```
 int extraHours =  hours - 40;
//insert "if(hours > 60)printf("Mistake...");
            float payForFortyHours = (float) (basePay * hours);


public float totalPay(double basePay, int hours){
//insert "(if(basePay < 8.00) printf("mistake");
```

Comment: It is an answer now. I made a mistake but yeah i needed a way to ask for more, unfortunately didn't notice the link lol. xD

Answer (score 0):

There're a few ways to go about this.  The approach you take depends upon your requirements.  If you merely want to print an error message, you can check your conditions and use System.out or System.err to emit your message:

```
if (conditionsNotMet)
  System.err.println("Error: Condition X is not met");
```

Take a look at the javadoc for System.out and System.err (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) -- They're both output streams, corresponding to stdout and stderr.  stderr is typically used for emitting error and log messages, but how each of these outputs is used is up to you, the developer.

If you wanted to abort processing, you might consider using an exception instead:

```
if (conditionsNotMet)
  throw new Exception("Condition X is not met");
```

Consider that exceptions can be a burden on developers.  Checked exceptions (http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129) must be declared to be thrown or caught.  In this case, perhaps that's what you want.

It's bad form to throw a java.lang.Exception -- seriously consider an exception that is more suited (such as IllegalArgumentExeception, in this case) or implement your own.  IllegalArgumentException is *not* a checked exception which might be good in your case.  As I mentioned, checked exceptions must be declared as thrown or caught in a try/catch block.  Seeing as IllegalArgumentException is not checked, you won't be forcing clients of your method to catch it.

Often it's still a good idea to document when a method throws an unchecked exception, though.  This informs other developers using your code the common conditions under which an exception is thrown allowing them to make a decision about catching or ignoring the exception.

Comment: you should NEVER throw `Exception`, this is terrible advice for someone learning Java. It leads to `catch(Exception e);` which is always wrong. The standard library `RuntimeException`, `IllegalArgumentException` is what should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to deal with this would be to test for what ever bad data you might encounter and to throw [IllegalArgumentException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) ( with a very detailed explanation of what was illegal and why ) or one of the other built in exceptions dealing with generic problems with invalid data.

You could also create your own sub classes of [RuntimeException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) for more specific cases. Like `BasePayLessThanZeroException` or `HoursLessThanZeroException` or `HoursGreaterThan168Exception`.

The most important take away is that the cause and possible remedies of the exceptions should be well stated a clear. `FILE NOT FOUND` without listing the location and name of the file you were looking for is terrible. `Could not find ~/settings.xml` is a much better exception message.

Answer (score 0):

This calls for an [exception](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

In the `totalPay` method

```
if (!someConditions)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Condition XY not met.")
```

In main: surround your code with a try-catch-block

```
try
{
    fooCorporation foo = new fooCorporation();
    System.out.println("employee 1: " + foo.totalPay(7.50,35));
    System.out.println("employee 2: " + foo.totalPay(8.20,47));
    System.out.println("employee 3: " + foo.totalPay(10.00,73));
}
catch(IllegalArgumentException ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Note: read the link I posted, exceptions can be a little bit confusing, but it's a very important concept in Java.

For further reading (once you now the basics) I would recommend [Exception Handling Antipatterns](http://today.java.net/article/2006/04/04/exception-handling-antipatterns). It covers some common mistakes regarding exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on where you want to print the error message. You can, of course, print from within the `totalPay()` method itself, but I'm guessing you're asking about changing the "signature" of `totalPay()` so that the code calling it knows an error occurred.

If so, you either do that by returning a special value that means an error occurred or by throwing an `Exception`. Either way, your calling code will have to check that a successful return occurred before it can print the result.

An example of using a special return value would be a negative number, or a special value like `java.lang.Float.NaN`.

An example of using an Exception would be:

```
try {
    System.out.println(foo.totalPay(8.20,47));
}
catch (InvalidTotalPayException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: you should NEVER throw `Exception` directly, this is terrible advice for someone learning Java.

Comment: Wow. I was just trying to show the two broad approaches: return an identifying value, throw "an Exception". I don't disagree that throwing a more specific Exception subclass is the right way to use that approach. And fair point that I shouldn't assume someone new to Java would know not to take the example exactly as-is.